# open and refresh a local web page in java

Tags: java, swing, browser

I need a way to open a web page on a browser (like the default),
the only problem is that I need to open the browser sending a url that ends with a parameter like: index.html?json=something

so far I've seen online only this method:

```
File f = new File("index.html");
        URI uri = f.toURI();
        desk.browse(uri);
```

but this way I can't open a webpage with a parameter and still I need to find a way to refresh the browser during the program executions.

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://some-site.com/?json=something");
//or also URI uri = new URL("http://some-site.com/?json=something").toURI();
desk.browse(uri);
```